# Lookup is not returning any values on Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

So, I am trying to pass a value from one cloud page to another and call a lookup function in AMP Script. But then my page hangs in the preview and never loads, and I am getting an ERROR 500 if I publish. In addition to that, both the variables are not being picked up on the receiving side.

This is the code that I am using to pass the values from the source page (where I tested and both variables hold the correct values)

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(426,'acid',@acid,'consentVersion',@consentVersion))=%%" class="cta cta--primary">
```

and this is how I am receiving it on the destination page:

```
%%[
var @acid, @consentVersion, @email, @dateOfBirth

set @acid = AttributeValue("acid")
set @consentVersion = AttributeValue("consentVersion")
set @email = Lookup("MASTER SUBSCRIBER", "EMAILADDRESS", "EUCI", @acid)
set @dateOfBirth = Lookup("MASTER SUBSCRIBER", "BIRTHDATE", "EUCI", @acid)
]%%
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the redirectto() function?

Comment: Didn't make it work, unfortunately. Using a QueryParameter() instead of AttributeValue() helped with reading the value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that I got from the Salesforce support:

> "The Data Extension Key field for a Lookup function call is invalid.
> The key field has a MAX or unlimited length. Fields with MAX or
> unlimited length cannot be used as keys."
>
> ... where the key field it's referring to being 'EUCI' (I know, I wish
> these errors were returned in the UI).
>
> In our database, this field does not have an explicit length limit.
> This might be the first time I've seen this, but it appears the UI
> allows the creation of MAX length fields by setting length to "-1".
>
> Given the database we're running, the MAX equivalent for a text field
> is going to be 4000 characters. You may be able to work around this
> error by creating text fields with length set explicitly to that
> number, which achieves the same result.
>
> I took that expression and placed it in a CloudPage in a test account
> and was able to do a lookup on a text field of length 4000. Meanwhile,
> the preview wouldn't even load when I set the length implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an AttributeValue function, while you should be using QueryParameter or RequestParameter to get a vale passed in the link:

- [QueryParameter](https://ampscript.guide/queryparameter/): This function retrieves a value from a URL query string, based on a defined parameter key.
- [RequestParameter](https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/): This function is similar to QueryParameter, but in addition to retrieving a value from a URL query string, it can also be used to retrieve form field values.

Source: https://ampscript.guide/

Also, as a best practice, you can add a conditional statement to avoid the 500 error in case the values are not passed correctly:

```
%%[
var @acid, @consentVersion, @email, @dateOfBirth

set @acid = AttributeValue("acid")
set @consentVersion = AttributeValue("consentVersion")

if not empty(@acid) and not empty(@consentVersion) then 
   set @email = Lookup("MASTER SUBSCRIBER", "EMAILADDRESS", "EUCI", @acid)
   set @dateOfBirth = Lookup("MASTER SUBSCRIBER", "BIRTHDATE", "EUCI", @acid)
endif
]%%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip! Now I am able to see the value passed to the destination page. But the Lookup still makes the page crash... and I am quite sure that those data extensions and fields exist. Could it be something with the permissions?

Comment: Do you have access to those DEs? Can you double-check that you have used all params in your lookup correctly: https://ampscript.guide/lookup/?

Comment: Yes, I can definitely query them using, for example, Query Studio. It is definitely weird and I am suspicious that the space character in the data extension name is creating an issue here. Otherwise, everything seems to be "by the book". I wrote to SF support as well, really interested to resolve this :)

Comment: Nope, space wouldn't create any issues here. The `@acid` value you are testing with exists in the `MASTER SUBSCRIBER` DE, right?

Comment: Yes, it does, I just triple checked.